# Localhost Doesn't Record Changes?

Tags: netbeans, xampp, localhost

I am really new to web development so maybe this is an obvious question, but I have set up a local web server using XAMPP and have been editing my html/css/javascript in NetBeans.

Usually I can make a change to the code in NetBeans and check the page out on the localhost and the changes will be recorded immediately, but sometimes I have to wait a few minutes before the changes will be reflected on the localhost no matter how many times I refresh/re-navigate to the page?  For example, if I get an error recorded in the console and then go back to my js file and remove the error, save, then navigate back to the page on the localhost, it will still pop up the same error on the same line, even if the line doesn't exist anymore!  This happens even if I edit the code in emacs or another text editor.

Is this normal?  Is this something to do with XAMPP, the browser, or neither?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of cache, your browser is caching pages. Clear your browser's cache to see the changes immediately.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your header. This should solve your problem

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
```